# App Script - hide everything except current worksheet control using custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make each button pressed activate the sheet, and hide the rest of the sheets.
I would like help to make the code work, I have tried several ways, but my head has stopped!
I've tried calling flush and sleep, but to no avail.

But in the end I really want to perform the following function:

Selecting the option in the submenu opens the little app becoming active.

Opening the worksheet, the previous one must be hidden

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const currentSheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();

function onOpen() {
  createMenuWithSubMenu();
}

function createMenuWithSubMenu() {
  var subMenu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Configurações")
    .addItem("⚙️ Validadores de Dados", "supportsheet")
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('❌ Não Utilizar ❌')
      .addItem(" Filtro RL03", "DBRL03")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem("⚙️ Filtro RL04", "DBRL04")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Dash07", "DBRL05")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Dash08", "DBRL06"))

  var subMenu1 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Acompanhamento Geral ")
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Relátorios')
      .addItem(" Geral Sem Filtro Anual", "RL01"))
      .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Dashboard')
      .addItem(" Geral Sem Filtro Anual Nº", "Dash01")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Geral Sem Filtro Anual %", "Dash02"))

  var subMenu2 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Hospitais ")
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Relátorios')
      .addItem(" Filtro Anual", "RL02")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Geral Anual", "RL03"))
      .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Dashboard')
      .addItem(" Filtro Individual Anual Nº", "Dash03")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Individual Anual %", "Dash04")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Mensal", "Dash07"))

  var subMenu3 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Testagem ")
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Relátorios')
      .addItem(" Geral Anual", "RL04")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro  Anual", "RL05"))
      .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Dashboard')
      .addItem(" Filtro Individual Anual Nº", "Dash05")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Individual %", "Dash06")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem(" Filtro Mensal", "Dash08"))   
    
  var subMenu4 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Envio  ")
    .addItem(" Relatório Anual", "RLHP01")
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem(" Relatório Mensal", "RLHP02")
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Solicitações ")
    .addItem(" Inicio", "Home")
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem(" Cadastro", "Database")
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(subMenu)
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(subMenu1)
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(subMenu2)
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(subMenu3)
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(subMenu4)
    .addToUi();
}


function Home() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Início');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha); 
}

function Database() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Database');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha); 
}

function supportsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Support Sheet');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RL01() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RL01');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RL02() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RL02');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RL03() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RL03');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RL04() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RL04');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RL05() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RL05');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function DBRL03() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('DBRL03');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function DBRL04() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('DBRL04');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function DBRL05() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('DBRL05');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function DBRL06() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('DBRL06');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash01() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash01');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash02() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash02');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash03() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash03');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash04() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash04');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash05() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash05');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash06() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash06');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash07() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash07');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function Dash08() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('Dash08');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RLHP01() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RLHP01');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}

function RLHP02() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var planilha = sheet.getSheetByName('RLHP02');
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(planilha);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554417/7215091

Comment: Close to what I need, or maybe I couldn't put it correctly in my code

Comment: Is this the same as your question? [How do I hide all sheets except one in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672573/1330560)

Comment: Different, as you can see my code has a wide function, and when I used this configuration the error, closing the next one to be displayed, I tried to fit it, I could be doing it wrong